# Getting out of memory exception while loading image using 'FFImageLoading.CachedImage' in xamrinform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to show list of images in single page as like gallery. In my xaml page I am creating single wrap view, in that wrap view I have 
add `ffimageloader` for loading images. Here I have gave list of image url' to that wrap view contain ffimageloader. When I called that page it shows fallowing error.

`system.outofmemoryexception: out of memory at ffimageloading.platformimageloadertask.....` like that. many post's suggest if we using ffimageloader  instead of image tag we will reduce this type of issues but still getting same issues after using this one also. I am running my application in xamarin android. Please suggest any idea.

Here is the sample code what I have tried

```xml
<CustomWrapView x:Name="SampleGalleryView" ItemsSource="{Binding GalleryImages}">
   <CustomWrapView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </CustomWrapView.ItemTemplate>
</CustomWrapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look at FFImageLoading's downsampling capabilities. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#downsampling-properties
- If you have a lot of items, you should use some view which is capable of doing items virtualisation (I suspect that WrapView isn't), like: `ListView` / `CarouselView`, etc